# Multiple Elements and CSS text overflow / ellipsis

Tags: css

Assume the following:

```
<li>
   <strong>Name:</strong>
   <span>John Doe</span>
</li>
```

The label part (the string in the `<strong>` tag) and the value part (the string in the `<span>` tag) can have any length. So, sometimes the label might be long and the value might be short, or vice versa, or both short, or both long.

When the combined width of the label and value exceeds a specified width, I'd like the tail-end of the concatenated string to display ellipsis. **How do I do this in CSS?**

**UPDATE**: what if the markup looked like this?

```
<dl>
   <dd>Name:</dd>
   <dt>John Doe</dt>
</dl>
```

Comment: The first will work as is using e.g. `li {
    white-space: nowrap; 
    width: 150px; 
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis; 
}` because both `<strong>` and `<span>` is `display: inline`. The second need to target the `dl dt` as it is `display: block`.

Comment: As you can see, also the display type matters, and for `text-overflow: ellipsis;` to work the element should be of type _block_ (e.g. "inline-block", "block", "flex", though _flex_ has some more things to look out for).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just set `text-overflow: ellipsis` on the containing `<li>`
 element.

```css
li {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis; 
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
     <strong>Name:</strong>
     <span>John Doe John Doe John Doe John Doe John Doe John Doe John Doe John Doe John Doe John Doe John Doe</span>
  </li>

  <li>
     <strong>Very long long long long long long long long long long long long Name:</strong>
     <span>John Doe</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

When working with a definition list, you can enclose `<dt>` and `<dd>` elements into a `<div>` (this is [explicitly](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-dt-element) [allowed](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-dd-element) by the spec since HTML5, but it works in a few older browsers, too). In this case, remember to style them with `display: inline` to display them in the same line of text.

```css
dl>div {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis; 
    white-space: nowrap;
}

dl>div>* {
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <div>
     <dd>Name:</dd>
     <dt>John Doe John Doe John Doe John Doe John Doe John Doe John Doe John Doe John Doe John Doe John Doe</dt>
  </div>

  <div>
     <dd>Very long long long long long long long long long long long long Name:</dd>
     <dt>John Doe</dt>
  </div>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 7):

You should use the following:

```
li {
    white-space: nowrap; 
    width: <your width> 
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis; 
}
```

Comment: I'm sure I tried this, but will test again.

Comment: What if the markup was a definition list, instead? There is no containing element for the `dt` and `dd` tags like there is for the first example (`li`). Would I just wrap the `dt` and `dd` in a, say, `span` tag? I need to markup to remain semantically correct and HTML5 valid.

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie, no you couldn't use a `span` tag. The [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl) state the permitted child elements of a `dl`. They mention a `div`, but don't give an example of it's use. You may find different browsers interpret the markup differently if tags are mixed.

Comment: Should I stay away from a definition list even though it's probably more semantically correct in my application? Or is there a way to look at the `dt` and `dd` as a single unit and apply the ellipses when their combined width exceeds some threshold?

Answer (score -2):

you can use this for li

```
li strong, li  span{
  width: 250px; /*change the width according to your choice */
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: inline;
  clear: both;
}
```

and for dl

```
dl dd, dl dt{
  width: 100px; /*change the width according to your choice */
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: inline;
  clear: both;
}
```

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie is issue resolved or not

Comment: For the definition list, the `dt` and `dd` should appear inline. Will your CSS work?

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie yes it should you can check

Comment: It's not appearing inline: https://jsfiddle.net/sd3ep2ow/.

Comment: Also - I only want the ellipsis to appear once -- at the end of the combined dt and dd string. I'm seeing two ellipsis: https://jsfiddle.net/sd3ep2ow/1/

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie check now answer is update

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183123/discussion-between-problem-solver-and-stackoverflownewbie).